# Isotope - masonry fluid columnWidth and gutter - media query

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I am using Isotope with masonry fluid columnWidth and gutter, and it seems works well.
I wrote some media queries for the responsive stuff, on desktop works well if I do the resize the window (infact take the correct value that I wrote in media queries).
My problem is that I can't understand why if I open this page with iphone, ios simulator or just "toggle device mode" in chrome, it doesn't take the last media query for the smallest devices.

I make a codepen, in the hope that someone can help me to solve.
http://codepen.io/mp1985/pen/OyBdwE

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .grid-item, .grid-sizer {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .grid-item--width2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .grid-item, .grid-sizer {
    width: 48.5%;
  }
  .grid-item--width2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

any ideas?
Many thanks
M.

Comment: I solved with this code in the head
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use max-width instead of min-width to target your breakpoints, use min-width for each additional breakpoint moving up from the smallest. Also you should do some research into what the recommended break point sizes are for different devices and orientations.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 301px) and (max-width: 500px) {
  .grid-item, .grid-sizer {
    width: 48.5%;
  }
  .grid-item--width2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .grid-item, .grid-sizer {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .grid-item--width2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried to add your media queries but it seems that I have always the same problem on mobile :(
it does't take the value of this media query but it still take the value of (min-width: 768px)  
how it is possible?

Comment: Where is min-width 768 coming from it's not in your demo code? Make sure you have them in the right order, your 320 break point should be right at the bottom.

Comment: min-width 768px is in the row 69.
I added your code at the bottom of the css as you can see in this new codepen, but it seems that it doesn't work if you open the page  with iphone, ios simulator or just "toggle device mode" in chrome 
http://codepen.io/mp1985/pen/dYgroZ